# How to make label anchor in github pages (MD syntax)

Tags: markdown, github-pages

Does anyone know markdown syntax to have anchor linking to label?

For instance:

```
Hello [text of link](#label)
... other content
#my label
```

Obviously # (hashtag) is used by MD (h1).. 
Important thing — I want to use this for github pages. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, founded the way -- using native html syntax works.

```
   #<a name="label></a>h1 label
```